# How to redraw opengl renderer after clicking button?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to update the gluLookAt() from the main UI thread of my opengl renderer I've tryed the requestRenderer() methode at the end of my code for my button but eclipes gives me sme errors with it I was just wondering what would be the best possible way to do this from the main UI thread?

Heres my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
GLSurfaceView ourSurface;
GLRenderer call;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ourSurface = new SurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FrameLayout v = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.Canvas);
    v.addView(ourSurface);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.pluseyex:
        break;
    case R.id.minuseyex:
      break;    
    case R.id.pluseyey:
        break;
    case R.id.minuseyey:
        break;
    case R.id.pluseyez:
        float z =call.getEyez()+1;
        call.setEyez(z);


        break;
    case R.id.minuseyez:
        break;
    }


}
```

Here is my Renderer:

```
public class SurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

private final GLRenderer mRenderer;

public SurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mRenderer = new GLRenderer();
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}

public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {

    public volatile float eyez =-5;

      public float getEyez() {
        return eyez;
    }

    public void setEyez(float eyez) {
        this.eyez = eyez;
    }

    private GLTriEX tri;
    //private GLCubeEX cube;
    public GLRenderer(){
        tri = new GLTriEX();
        //cube = new GLCubeEX();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
        gl.glClearColor(.8f, 0f, .2f, 1f);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);

        //long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()% 4000L;
        //float angle =.090f * ((int)time);
        //gl.glRotatef(angle, 1, 0, 2);

        tri.draw(gl);
        //cube.draw(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);//bottom left corrnor
        float ratio = (float) width/height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 25);
        //gl.glFrustumf(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar)

    }



}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using your `eyez` value anywhere in your `Renderer`.

I think you probably want to replace

> `GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);`

by

> `GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, eyez, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);`

to actually see any effect from pressing the button.

Comment: I tried it but the view stays the same I added in a call to the GlSurfaceView.sequestered() and still doesn't work. I also tried putting the onclick() in the GlSurfaceView and at the end of the button code put sequestered() still nothing